# Reference request: a list of (small) finite simple groups

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, simple-groups

I am currently in the midst of a project in which it would be useful to have a list of all (small) simple groups as a means to check calculations, not waste time, verify conjectures for small examples, etc.

I found [this](https://www.mimuw.edu.pl/~zbimar/small_groups.pdf) list which enumerates all groups of order $\leq 100$. This tells me that something like this is technically possible, and likely already exists, but I've not been able to find it.

**Edit:** Perhaps I should have mentioned this: I do not want something like the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_finite_simple_groups) which has a table of the different types of simple groups. I would like something similar to the [first link](https://www.mimuw.edu.pl/~zbimar/small_groups.pdf), which lists all groups with order $x$, then all groups of order $x+1$, etc.

---

I'm not sure how much more specificity I can add, but I'd be happy to answer any questions if I'm unclear.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_finite_simple_groups

Comment: Besides the groups with prime order the smallest such group is $\ A_5\ $ and has order $\ 60\ $

Comment: Have you considered https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UTby_e4-Rhg?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a list of orders of nonabelian simple groups up to 10000. Of course, in addition, there is a abelian simple group of order each prime. You can already see from this short list that the most frequently occurring type of group is ${\rm PSL}(2,q)$ for prime powers $q$.

60: $A_5 \cong {\rm PSL}_2(4) \cong {\rm PSL}_2(5)$.

168: ${\rm PSL}_2(7) \cong {\rm PSL}_3(2)$.

360: $A_6 \cong {\rm PSL}_2(9)$.

504: ${\rm PSL}_2(8)$.

660: ${\rm PSL}_2(11)$.

1092: ${\rm PSL}_2(13)$.

2448: ${\rm PSL}_2(17)$.

2520: $A_7$.

3420: ${\rm PSL}_2(19)$.

4080: ${\rm PSL}_2(16)$.

5616: ${\rm PSL}_3(3)$.

6048: ${\rm PSU}_3(3)$.

6072: ${\rm PSL}_2(23)$.

7800: ${\rm PSL}_2(25)$.

7920: $M_{11}$.

9828: ${\rm PSL}_2(27)$.

Comment: Thanks! How (or where) did you find these?

Comment: I got them from the ATLAS of Finite Groups, but it is straightforward to calculate such lists using the classification of finite simple groups, and verret gave a link to a much longer such list.

Answer (score 5):

http://www.madore.org/~david/math/simplegroups.html

Here is a list (in the nonabelian case), up to ten billion.

Answer (score 1):

Use [GAP](https://www.gap-system.org/)! It has detailed knowledge of many [small](https://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/pkg/SmallGrp-1.4.1/doc/chap1.html#X7C16EA1580AC7586) groups [out of the box](https://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap50.html), plays nicely with Sage, and lets you check calculations, etc., by writing programs.